# How to extract values from &mut iterator?

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, mutability

I am trying to make an iterator that maps a string to an integer:

```
fn main() {
    use std::collections::HashMap;

    let mut word_map = HashMap::new();

    word_map.insert("world!", 0u32);

    let sentence: Vec<&str> = vec!["Hello", "world!"];

    let int_sentence: Vec<u32> = sentence.into_iter()
        .map(|x| word_map.entry(x).or_insert(word_map.len() as u32))
        .collect();

}
```

([Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4f0c02873eb45b3e92c940961e5eebd4&version=stable&backtrace=0))

This fails with

> the trait `core::iter::FromIterator<&mut u32>` is not implemented for the type `collections::vec::Vec<u32>`

Adding a dereference operator around the `word_map.entry().or_insert()` expression does not work as it complains about borrowing which is surprising to me as I'm just trying to copy the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The borrow checker uses lexical lifetime rules, so you can't have conflicting borrows in a single expression.  The solution is to extract getting the length into a separate `let` statement:

```
let int_sentence: Vec<u32> = sentence.into_iter()
        .map(|x| *({let len = word_map.len() as u32;
                    word_map.entry(x).or_insert(len)}))
        .collect();
```

Such issues will hopefully go away when Rust supports [non-lexical lifetimes](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/).